# Seam components isn't injected within an ExtendedDataModel child

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, richfaces, seam

I'm trying to use a child of Seam's `ExtendedDataModelClass` as a data source for `rich:dataTable` component:

```html
<rich:dataTable id="docPackList" var="pack" width="100%" rows="25"
    value="#{specDocPackageList.dataModel}">
...
</rich:table>
```

Within this child's `walk` method I call a `getResultList` method of controller derived from Seam's `EntityQUery`. This controller has some fields injected with Seam:

```
@Name("specDocPackageList")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class SpecDocPackageList extends EntityQuery<DocPackage> {

    @In(create = true, value = "orgunitList")
    private OrgUnitList orgUnitListController;

    public OrgUnitList getOrgUnitListController() {
        return orgUnitListController;
    }

    public void setOrgUnitListController(OrgUnitList orgUnitListController) {
        this.orgUnitListController = orgUnitListController;
    }

    private SelectableQueryDataModel entityQueryDataModel;

    @Override
    public DataModel getDataModel() {
        if (entityQueryDataModel == null) {
            entityQueryDataModel = SelectableQueryDataModel.getInstance(this);
        }
        return entityQueryDataModel;
    }
    ...
}

public class SelectableQueryDataModel<T, K> extends ExtendedDataModel {

    private EntityQuery<T> dataProvider;

    public SelectableQueryDataModel(EntityQuery<T> query) {
        dataProvider = query;
        ...
    }

    public static SelectableQueryDataModel getInstance(EntityQuery query) {
        return new SelectableQueryDataModel(query);
    }

    public void walk(FacesContext facesContext, DataVisitor dataVisitor, Range range, Object o) throws IOException {
        ...
        for (T item : this.dataProvider.getResultList()) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is I have `null` in `specDocPackageList.orgUnitListController` when `specDocPackageList.getResultList()` is called from `SelectableQueryDataModel.walk` method. No excpetion is thrown at that point. However, this field is injected in the right way when `getResultList()` is called to get data for `rich:dataTable`:

```html
<rich:dataTable id="docPackList" var="pack" width="100%" rows="25"
    value="#{specDocPackageList.resultList}">
...
</rich:table>
```

Why doesn't Seam inject this field in the first case and do that in the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that you're passing `EntityQuery` in the constructor of your `SelectableQueryDataModel`. You should not keep component references around, if you do interception could not work properly.

You're better off passing the component's name and using `Component.getInstance()` from within `SelectableQueryDataModel` to make Seam's interceptor chain work as advertised. Alternatively, you can pass the class and use `Component.getInstance(Class<?>)` to retrieve the component of the requested class type (the latter however requires that EntityQuery is subclassed for each list you use).